# In Jmeter, how to add sample menu for load test of webservice in version 3.0?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to see option to add web service request in Jmeter load test, but I'm not able to find menu option in samples. How can I make this option available in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Under `Sampler`, there is `SOAP/XML-RPC Request` for SOAP web services.
2. Under `Sampler`, you can use `HTTP Request` for REST services. More info on this is [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/).

If you do not see them, ensure if you have java 7 at  least in the %PATH%. check for any ERROR in the jmeter-log. Easiest option is to do a fresh download jmeter3.0 once again & check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `WebService(SOAP) Request` - it has been removed after JMeter version 2.9. Currently it is recommended to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for building web service requests. You may also need [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to sent `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers if required.

You can get a SOAP Web Service test plan "skeleton" in a couple of clicks using JMeter Templates feature, from JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Building a SOAP Web Service Test Plan` -> Create

[image: JMeter SOAP Web Service]

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for more detailed information on JMeter setup for web services testing.